# BOA Aegir Octopus, APC disabled: Module's php files seem to be cached, changes are not reflected. Why?

Tags: caching, aegir

I installed BOA on a VPS and everything seems quite alright except the fact that when I change a module's php file, the changes are not reflected in the website.

When I change something in drupal's index.php I can see the changes.

My first thought was APC which I disabled globally in php.ini for testing but that didn't help.

It looks like the file is never called, though I double checked that I'm working in the right directory and drupal setup.

Obviously I'm missing something and even Google didn't shed light no this.

Do you know what this could be?

Comment: What are you changing in the module file? If you're altering the content of a hook it's likely you'll need to clear Drupal's caches for the changes to show

Comment: I'm migrating a site which lived outside aegir before, and wondered why my changes to some hook_form_alter were not applied.

And of course I cleared drupals caches.



so i simply put a die('something'); in the first line of the module file in order to see whether it is called, but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I got it.

Funnily it had nothing to do with Apc, Redis or the drupal cache :)

In the site I migrated for some reason I don't know, were copies of several modules inside one module which were not in use. I played around with the features module a while ago, maybe this was the reason for that.

When importing the site Aegir apparently looks for the directories of the modules and it found one of my modules in that additional place and stored it in the system table.

So drupal thought the module lived there, and never ever called the "real" module version.

I found this out by calling [drupal_get_filename](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_filename/6) which returned a strange path like
"sites/all/modules/vocabindex/ppp/mymodule"
and by looking into the original site I was astonished to find about 15 modules there.

In the end I simply delete the whole vocabindex directory as we don't use the module anymore and now everything seems fine. Yay!

Maybe this will save someone a lot of time at some point.

Thanks Clive and Grace for your help!
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Clearing Drupal cache may be not enough in this case.

Since Redis is active by default, it may still cache some include paths, or there can be old paths still present in your system table, so you need to run the "Rebuild registry" task followed by "Flush all caches" task (the second is the same as running `drush cc all` on command line).

If this still doesn't help, upgrade to latest BOA-2.0.6-dev (head), which includes recent APC 3.1.14 version to avoid this [known APC bug](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC&release=3.1.14).